# Update double nested array script

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array, set

I'm trying to write a script to add a new field in a double nested array without deleting the entire array.

I'm trying to add a new field `totalStudents` to `School.teacher.class`,

This is the structure:

```
Work: [...],

School: [{
           name: {type: String, default: ''},
           teacher: 
               [{ 
                 class: {
                     enabled: {type: Boolean, default: true},
                     grade: [{type: String, default: ''}],
                 },
                 test: {
                     enabled: {type: Boolean, default: false},
                     duration: {type: Number, default: 5},
                 },
                 score: {type: Number, default: 0},
               }]
            curve: 
               [{
                 lower: {type: Number, default: 0},
                 upper: {type: Number, default: 0},
                 withinBoundary: {type: Boolean, default: false},
                 outsideBoundary: {type: Boolean, default: false},
                 enabled: {type: Boolean, default: true}
               }]
        }],
```

The code that I wrote:

```
db.colllection.updateMany({}, {$set: {School: [{teacher:[{class:{totalStudents: null}}]}]}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to add that field in your schema in `class` object,

```
class: {
  enabled: {type: Boolean, default: true},
  grade: [{type: String, default: ''}],
  totalStudents: { type: Number }
},
```

If you are trying to insert in all array elements then you can try positional array operator to set field in all the elements,

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
{
  $set: {
    "School.$[].teacher.$[].class.totalStudents": null
  }
})
```